# How is a question about ports and sockets on topic at Programmers?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, flagging, declined-flags

I just flagged this question about [the difference between a port and a socket](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/171734/38148) as off-topic. My flag was declined. Can someone explain to me how is this question related to programmers? To me, it's more related to network stuff which don't really belong here in my opinion.

Comment: Why would you think network programming is off topic?

Comment: Well there is no indication in the OP's post about network *programming*... The top-voted answer goes about how the OS handles protocols like TCP and UDP. I don't see anything programming-related in this.

Comment: The question is asking for an explanation of two concepts that you'll most certainly meet if you do any kind of network programming. It has problems (lack of research, for example), but topicality isn't one of them...

Comment: Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A socket is inherently an interface that an OS provides to applications to communicate via an address, so I feel this question is relevant to a programmer.  I don't see sockets as being a major concern for system administrators or network engineers but they certainly matter to software developers writing a network interface.